# Fresh ubuntu 20 server losing ethernet network after reboot?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 20 server, rebooted, and the network is gone. It's connected with ethernet. I didn't change any network settings. It's happened twice. Rebooting multiple times does nothing. I reinstalled, and it did it again.

What steps can I take to debug this?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: No such version as version 20. It will either be 20.04 or 20.10 which is it?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1. netplan wasn't modified and it was using DHCP. I erased the build so cant copy it right now. Ubuntu 18.04 works fine.